# Mercurial changegroup hook is being passed wrong HG_URL

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I've setup a simple changegroup hook for my Mercurial repositories to email the set of changes to interested users. I'd like to use a single script for every repository I manage, and I would also like to identify the repository the changegroup came from. According to the Mercurial *Hooks* documentation, the environment variable HG_URL is available for this purpose. However, I am not getting what I'm expecting from this variable:

expected:

```
https://repo01/hg/project
```

actual:

```
remote:https::rnideffer
```

Why is this the URL, and how do I get what I expected into the changegroup hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `changegroup` hook can't always tell the remote URL being used.  From the [Hooks chapter of the Mercurial Book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html):

> When possible, Mercurial will tell a
>   hook the location of the “far side” of
>   an activity that transfers changeset
>   data between repositories. This is
>   provided by Mercurial in a Python
>   parameter named url, or an environment
>   variable named HG_URL. No comments
>
> This information is not always known.
>   If a hook is invoked in a repository
>   that is being served via http or ssh,
>   Mercurial cannot tell where the remote
>   repository is, but it may know where
>   the client is connecting from. In such
>   cases, the URL will take one of the
>   following forms: No comments
>
> remote:ssh:1.2.3.4—remote ssh client,
>   at the IP address 1.2.3.4. No comments
>
> remote:http:1.2.3.4—remote http
>   client, at the IP address 1.2.3.4. If
>   the client is using SSL, this will be
>   of the form remote:https:1.2.3.4. No
>   comments

So you're being told they're pushing via https from a machine named rnideffer.

Have you considered using the [notify extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/NotifyExtension)?  It ships with mercurial, does pretty much exactly what you're describing, and can be provided with the URL prefix necessary to turn repo names into the URLs you want.

Comment: Great explanation. I found that the PWD environment variable is passed in by apache and contains the absolute path of the repository on disk, which I can use for my needs. I am using a changegroup hook instead of notify because I want emails for every pushed gropu of changes, not every single change.

Comment: Glad it helped, though the NotifyExtension does changegroups too.  It has both 'changegroup' and 'changeset' support.  See the `hooks` section of this http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NotifyExtension